# Permanently hide form page after being submitted using Wordpress & Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using **Wordpress** and am using **[Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/)** to create "Questionaire" page.

This is the case that am trying to achieve:

1. User logged in.
2. Redirect user to "Questionaire page".
3. User succesfully submitted their answer.
4. User logout.
5. User logged in again, they won't see "Questionaire page" anymore because they already submitted their answer in Step 2. Instead redirect them to another page.

Am not quite sure whether this will be helpful or not. This is the sample code for Questionaire in using contact form 7:

```
<p>1. Which secondary school did you attend?<br />
[text* q1] </p>

<p>2. What do you plan to do immediately after secondary school?<br />
[text* q2] </p>


<p>[submit "Send"]</p>
```

Comment: Are you storing submissions after users have submitted them? You would need to keep track of who has submitted the questionnaire so that you can prevent them from seeing it again. Or at the very least you will need to store some user_meta data so that you can check that before displaying the form using a filter or action.

Contact form 7 might not be the best solution and you may want to look into an alternate form plugin that has more features.

Comment: Yeah i data will be stored and thats the same logic i was thinking but not really sure how to write the code. I would consider myself as amateur in coding. Thanks for your reply @jrod!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ($user->ID != 0) {
        $status = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'FORM_STATUS', 'FORM_STATUS_VALUE');
        if ($status != 'SOMETHING') {
            //Do stuff
        }
        else {
            //Do stuff
        }
    }

?>
```

then after form submit you can redirect user to another page, and in this page change `get_user_meta($user->ID, 'FORM_STATUS', 'FORM_STATUS_VALUE_NEW')`

to redirect after form submit http://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/